# Find value of a line integral using Stokes' theorem

Tags: integration, vector-fields

Given a vector field 
$\vec A = y\vec i + z\vec j + x\vec k$
Use Stokes' formula to calculate the line integral $\oint\limits_C {\vec Ad\vec r} $
in here, $C$ is a circle
${x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = {a^2}$ intersects
$x + y + z = 0$

Comment: (a) What have you tried? (b) this is more of a mathematics problem than a physics problem.

Comment: I am not familiar with this type of integral. I found it in a Physics textbook (Mathematics for physicist)

Comment: But every students majored in Physics would encounter this kind of problem, I am a physics-majored student

Comment: @ChrisWhite On Math.SE they are probably also not very happy with just copied questions without any shown effort.

Comment: For future reference: *mathematical physics* doesn't mean "any mathematics in the context of a physics problem". And I would also suggest migrating this to Math.SE since there is no physics to be explained here and that is what Physics.SE is all about. On Math.SE, they will still ask you to show your own work but the question *would* be on topic there.